# How many pixels is 1em in IE8?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Isn't 1em supposed to be 16px across all browsers?

I have this CSS

```
* {font-size: 1em; }
label { font-size: .85em; }
```

which on IE8 strangely gives label elements a height of 12px vs. the 13.6px I was hoping for.

Comment: I'm still forking out CSS, trying to find any px-set heights. So could be an error on my behalf, too

Comment: Sanity check: you've not got the "Zoom" or "Text Size" browser settings at anything other than the default, have you? I *think* the IE8 browser style sheet defaults to 16px, as you're expecting.

Comment: @MattGibson: didn't touch either one.

Comment: Recommendation: set your font sizes with pixels. Makes life hell of a lot easier and you still can zoom without problems.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Isn't 1em supposed to be 16px across all browsers?

Not necessarily:

> One 'Em'(1em) is equal to the height of the capital letter "M" in the default font size. When applied in CSS, the Em represents either the user's default font size, or the size of the parent element's font size, if one is available.

So while the default font size is 16px, perhaps you have a different size set on IE.

Also you may have some obscure parent element that is overriding it.

[More info](http://www.guistuff.com/css/css_units.html)

Comment: Found it. External CSS file overriding some of my classes. So, it's 16px after all. Thx

Comment: @frequent i run IE with the option to disable CSS from specifying font sizes. Too many web-sites decide to use a different *"normal"* font size (instead hard-coding some value like `9pt` or `16px`). Just a reminder to *not be that guy*.

Answer (score 3):

The unit em is relative.If you have a fontsize of 12pt, 1 em = 12pt. Using a fontsize of 20pt, 1 em = 20pt . It is derived from the letter M. It dates from the time and period when texts were created by a compositor. The letter M was the size of a square of the corpus .